# How to display GMT date and time NOT the local time in a label

Tags: c#, datetime

I currently use:

```
lable1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

to display the short date time in my `label1`.

Because the code above shows the date from windows machine (if you change the date in windows clock settings date in program is also changed) this doesn't help me any more. I need to display the GMT date and time in `label1` (GMT+0 date) and label2 (GMT+0 clock), so that the date and time will be displayed independent from windows machine clock settings.

I don't have any clue how to make this. Remember that I have a 24 hour system not 12.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is the current local time. `DateTime.UtcNow` is the current UTC time.

Comment: You need to use `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm")` (or similar) rather than `ToShortDateString()` if you want to always have a 24 hour clock (rather than it being based on the culture).

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435099/c-how-to-get-datetime-from-the-internet) maybe can help you.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: that's a *little* bit overkill.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel yes, the point is he cannot retrieve the datetime from the local machine he have to use an external server.

Comment: No he doesn't. `DateTime` has the `UtcNow` property, which equals `GMT`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel [UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) return the GMT of the local machine.

Comment: Thanks all for helping. I got my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `UtcNow` property like this:

```
label1.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString();
```