# Compare 2 different date/time from database in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get date and time from database then use it to compare with current date and time. I'm able to get time from database and compare it with the computer's time but I want to use a specific time which is same for everyone. Basically I want to get time from web. I couldn't figure NTP and SNTP

```
if (myReader.HasRows)
{
    myReader.Read();
    var expiryDate = myReader.GetDateTime("expirationdate");
    if (DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2) > expiryDate)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Why do you think using `UtcNow` is not right? Can you please be more specific? There are some way to calculate NTP time as well. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1193955/447156

Comment: @SonerGönül - I think he wants to get the Date from Internet. may be he needs tp go throw web services.

Comment: You want database `datetime` compare with any user `local datetime` depends from timezone?.

Comment: You can find how to Get the time from the Web here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435099/how-to-get-datetime-from-the-internet

Comment: @SonerGönül I'm not sure is it allowed to write in foreign language but i'll try my chance. "Bu kodu kullanıcı giriş yaparken kullanıyorum ve ücretli,süreli üyelik sistemim var veritabanından zamanı kontrol ediyor ve giriş hakkı veriyor ama kullanıcı bilgisayar saatini geri alırsa süresi bitmiş olsa bile giriş yapabiliyor bunu engellemek için saati internet üzerinden çekmek istiyorum NTP ve SNTP ile nasıl yapabileceğimi çözemedim." Your profile shows you're from Istanbul then you can speak Turkish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reading your Turkish explanation, and assuming "database" is MS SQL Server (I don't understand why people don't tell what the "database" is), you can directly get the date and time from your database. If you mean the database server is the local computer then for getting time from internet, check:

[Get Datetime from internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435099/how-to-get-datetime-from-the-internet)

Comment: It's MySQL I've found this question before but I couldn't figure it out. Is there any other guide line for this ?

Comment: What part of it you couldn't figure out? It is very simple. You can query current timestamp from MySQL, no? For example you could do: new DateTime.ParseExact( (string)OleDbCommand( "select now()", yourConnection ).ExecuteScalar(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").

Comment: I don't use MySQL but postgreSQL and SQL server, didn't think of MySQLConnection, you can use that. OleDb is universal, you can use with any database that has OleDb provider.

Comment: Btw I get this error The type name 'ParseExact' does not exist in the type 'DateTime'. Then I'll change my whole my connection code as OleDb. and i'm using Reader Does OleDb support it?

Comment: ParseExact doesn't exist ????? Which version of .Net are you using (as far as I know it even existed back in .Net 1.0). Probably you are doing something wrong, I will give a sample with OleDb (leaving connection string part empty), you can continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
  string result; 
  using (var con = new OleDbConnection(@"..."))
  {
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand("select now()",con);
    con.Open();
    result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
  }

  DateTime now = DateTime.ParseExact(result, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
  Console.WriteLine(now);
}
```

Comment: This is the error I'm getting System.DateTime' türündeki nesne 'System.String' türüne atılamadı.

Comment: MySQL documentation claims that it returns a string. It is you who use MySQL, and it is better if it is returning a DateTime, you don't need the casting from string and can directly use the DateTime.