# How to get a DateTime from Internet and compare using C#

Tags: c#, datetime

How to get Date Time from Internet and compare with one specific date, if the date is equal and greater then allow to register page else redirect application closed the page. My below code have one issue is that if a user will change system date, then its going to redirect to register page. That's why I need internet and redirect based on condition. And one more thing I am executing my application in local host.

Below is my C# code:

```
string date = "01/04/2016";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (DateTime.Today>=myDate)
{   
    // Allow redirect to registration page.
}
else
{      
    Response.Redirect("ApplicationClosed.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Nothing here is using the *Client* date time. Its using *Server* date time. You can change it, as its probably running on your machine (The *server*), but users of your website will not be able to affect the date returned by `DateTime.Today`

Comment: That looks like ASP.Net code. The only risk is that if the user changes the date *on the server*. But if that's your risk model, you can't save yourself. You can't trust (your) code running on someone else's machine.

Comment: This post refer to Internet time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435099/how-to-get-datetime-from-the-internet

Comment: I got answer, because I am in local server that why taking time from my system, if I will host into live then it will take from live server time. @Jamiec

Comment: Yes the code is asp.net code, as I add registration start date like 01/04/2016, can I add closing date for my registration and my closing date is 20/05/2016.@Damien_The_Unbeliever