# Real Date and Time

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, ntp, datetimeoffset

I have an audit trail where the date and time of user's time in / time out was enlisted. Is it possible that even I changed the system date and time. It ignores the system date/time that I have changed and log the real date and time of time in/ time out of the user.

This is my code.

```
dbAuditTrail.AddActionLog(userID, timeIn, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

Comment: Real date time of what? which country? which area? there are many factors..

Comment: Changed how? Where does the code run? And why are you storing an arbitrary string that can't be parsed as a DateTime in the database, instead of an actual `DateTime` value?

Comment: Real DateTime of gmt + 8 areas for example.

Comment: That's not what you wrote in the question. Do you want to store the altered system time or not? In any case, if you want the offset use `DateTimeOffset.Now`. And store *that* in the database, as a `datetimeoffset` type, not the string represantation

Comment: Please clarify what your question is really about. Right now it is kinda hard to understand what you're asking, in particular because you've also brought up the problem with time zones in a comment. Please write out a question with all the details.

Comment: I change system time means ?? your are changing time from Server ? or the User's Machine?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that's not a good duplicate, it doesn't have an answer at all. The link provided by Patrick Hofman is better, it contains multiple solutions that call NIST directly or through a web service. I start to suspect though that the OP is confused about UTC and local times, or doesn't know about DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: I didn't mark it as duplicate, I marked it as unclear, community decided to close it as a duplicate. I reopened it because I agree that the duplicate closure was wrong, but it wasn't my fault :) I still think the question as it stands is unclear though but now I can't cast a new vote in that regard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DateTime from the internet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435099/how-to-get-datetime-from-the-internet)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, get the date and time from an external service (NTP server for example) you trust.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435207/993547) suggests to use the NIST.gov webservice.

Comment: The OP seems to ask about the opposite - the "system time" was changed but the code doesn't store the changed time.

Comment: "log the real date and time of time in/ time out of the user" > as in 'not influenced by the user'. This is what he needs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you seem to have an opinion on everyones answers but haven't supplied any of your own.  If the user is after the real time, and the system time cannot be relied upon what do you suggest. Going to an external service to get the real time and then add or minus any time to a local time.

Comment: @SimonPrice Please read the question again. The way it's worded it asks why the altered time isn't stored, which doesn't make much sense. The OP's comments seem to suggest he wants the real time. If the OP doesn't understand the difference, no answer will help. As for reliable time, i'd ensure the DB server's watch synchronizes with a UTP server and use a default value in the database. That's not what the OP asked though.

Comment: then offer your own answer than be a keyboard warrior against everyone else

Comment: @SimonPrice to which question? Or all of them? Since all of them *have* been answered already, shouldn't I close the question instead? What do *you* understand from this question?

Comment: "log the real date and time of time in/ time out of the user" tells me that he wants the real time

Comment: @SimonPrice the full phrase is `It ignores the system date/time that I have changed and log the real date and time of time in/ time out of the user.` It has the opposite meaning, although it doesn't make sense