# How to Fetch Current Time from Internet?

Tags: asp.net

How to fetch current time from Internet to a `TextBox` using C#?

I tried with following code:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.UtcNow; 
DateTimeOffset dto2 = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
```

But it only returns correct Date.

Comment: try with DateTime.Now

Comment: It only return system date...i want google time and date

Comment: "[From internet](https://www.google.nl/search?q=internet+it+crowd&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU0JCE6OnTAhXnCMAKHXbCDa8Q_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=945)". That's rather vague...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DateTime from the internet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435099/how-to-get-datetime-from-the-internet)

Comment: some code formatting, some grammar

Answer (score 0):

For environments where port 13 is blocked, time from NIST can be web scraped as below,

```
public static DateTime GetNistTime()
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://nist.time.gov/actualtime.cgi?lzbc=siqm9b");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore); //No caching
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string html = stream.ReadToEnd();//<timestamp time=\"1395772696469995\" delay=\"1395772696469995\"/>
        string time = Regex.Match(html, @"(?<=\btime="")[^""]*").Value;
        double milliseconds = Convert.ToInt64(time) / 1000.0;
        dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(milliseconds).ToLocalTime();
    }

    return dateTime;
}
```