# C# - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay is different on my other comptuter by 2 seconds, how do I get accurate time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to get the same time on all Instances of my program. How do I do that. DateTime.Now is not accurate(is different on different hardware) enough, I need to get the Time down to 100 ms difference-precision.

Comment: It would really help if you explained [why you think you need this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want it read locally from each computer, as you don't know that each PC's clock is perfectly in sync (and you can see that they aren't).

So you have two options:

1. Write something on each computer to maintain precise time.
2. Get a web based time and all of your computers will be reading the same data. Here is an example from SO: [How to get DateTime from the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435099/how-to-get-datetime-from-the-internet)