# How make Own license-key in CSharp

Tags: c#, registry, registration, license-key, hardware-id

I Have Some Problem with Some One Copy My Program exe , So i want make a single Code for each PC and Register My Program !!
How Can Make That Single Code ( Computer ID or HardWare ID or ...) in C# ? 
and Check it !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [License for C# desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624149/license-for-c-sharp-desktop-application)

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic. However, look at the sister site "Software Recommendations": https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35437/licensing-activation-software

Comment: You think you're going to be able to solve a problem that plagued that game industry for years and was only really "solved" by forcing always on connection to their own servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a one library application and follow  following step.

1. master page inherit one page. so this page call dll.
2. this dll check license file exists or not
3. if not exists then redirect to register license page and provide key. this key validate your database.
4. if exists  then check license file read its ok for mac id and processor id.

dll
1. create one authentication interface
2. design abstract class and implement interface. here define your logic to get pc mac id, process id used to create 1 encrypted text file and ext is .lis.
3. this master page inherit. so every time execute logic. check the file is correct  mac and processor id.

Comment: need a simple Code to find Mac id in C# form

Comment: follow this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/66/getting-mac-address-of-client-machine-in-c-sharp.aspx